# Spring MVC, pattern doesn't work properly in case of forward slash symbol in path variable

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have such method in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/action/{actionType:root/testaction}")
public String test( @PathVariable String actionType) {        
}
```

When I do get request with url `localhost/action/root/testaction`- this method is not called.
But when I change method like:

```
@RequestMapping("/action/root/{actionType:testaction}")
public String test( @PathVariable String actionType) {        
}
```

And do the same get request - method works OK. The problem is that I want to include '/root' part into PathVariable string.

Could you clarify what can be wrong in my code?

Comment: Why do you want a forward slash in your path variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that path variables may not contain "/" characters, because that makes the parsing harder.

The Spring `@RequestMapping` feature partly implements [RFC 6570: URI Template](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570). That standard does not allow "/" [characters in variable names](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-2.3):

```
 variable-list =  varspec *( "," varspec )
 varspec       =  varname [ modifier-level4 ]
 varname       =  varchar *( ["."] varchar )
 varchar       =  ALPHA / DIGIT / "_" / pct-encoded

 modifier-level4 =  prefix / explode
 prefix        =  ":" max-length
 max-length    =  %x31-39 0*3DIGIT   ; positive integer < 10000
 explode       =  "*"
```

Comment: That's pretty sad, so it seems there is no good workaround for my case